# Where is vendor's OpenGL driver located in Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl, dll, location, driver

I'm going try to experiment C# with OpenGL modern driver in Windows 10 and I'm trying to find it.

As I have understand the standard driver `Openg32.dll`, which is located at `%systemroot%\system32` is an old one and seems to be it's from Microsoft, am I right?

I came to this conclusion, because of using the next command:

`dumpbin opengl32.dll /exports`

And found the function:

`11    A 00090330 glBegin`

As I remember, this function as `glLoadIdentity, glMultMatrix, glTranslate, glRotate` are deprecated and NOT included since OpenGL 3.2+, because you have to do matrix math on your own & use shaders.

OK, I begin to search at NVidia directory (the vendor of my video card is NVidia) `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation`, but have found only OpenCL drivers `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\OpenCL`:

- OpenCL.dll
- OpenCL64.dll

Any of them is perfectly dumped via: `dumpbin /exports`
But I can't find here the OpenGL driver exactly. Maybe it has some specific name like `nvdisps.dll` or something else?

PS (if you ask me about)

- I know about, that it's more recommended to use C++ for this stuff
- I don't want to use already done libraries
- I want `P/Invoke` stuff and just try to do it with C#

Comment: This is documented: [FAQ - OpenGL.org: How Does It Work On Windows?](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#How_Does_It_Work_On_Windows.3F).

Answer (score 5):

The `opengl32.dll` acts as a "conduit" toward the actual OpenGL driver, the so called "ICD" (Installable Client Driver); it also contains OpenGL-1.1 fallback code, since OpenGL has been part of the Win32-API application binary interface contract (i.e. programs running on Win95b or WinNT-4 or later can expect a working OpenGL-1.1 implementation).

The vendor ICD registers itself (in the Windows registry, for details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the `opengl32.dll` loads the appropriate ICD. The name of the ICD is not fixed. You can easily find the used ICD, by passing an invalid pointer to a OpenGL function that expects a buffer; the access violation will happen inside the ICD's code.